# A spherical version of the generalized half-angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

The following is a generalization of the half-angle formulas presented at [Nabla - Applications of Trigonometry](http://www.nabla.hr/GE-AppTrigonomB1.htm).

**Generalization**. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be the sides of a general convex quadrilateral, $s$ is the semiperimeter, and  $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are opposite angles, then
$$ad\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=(s-a)(s-d)\qquad\qquad bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+ad\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=(s-b)(s-c).\tag{1}$$
I am interested in the following:
**a)** If possible, a spherical generalization of $(1)$.
**b)** If **a)** is answered in the affirmative, what [classical metric relations of spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Half-angle_and_half-side_formulae) would follows from **a)** (or a particular case of a)?

This question is related to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting the quadrilateral along an appropriate diagonal (say, of length $p$) gives triangles with sides $a$, $d$, $p$  and $b$, $c$, $p$. By the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), we can write
$$\cos a \cos d + \sin a \sin d \cos \alpha = \cos p = \cos b \cos c+\sin b \sin c \cos \gamma \tag1$$
Or, using the shorthand $\overline{x}:=\sin x$, $\ddot{x}:=\cos x$,
$$\ddot{a} \ddot{d} + \overline{a} \overline{d} \ddot{\alpha} = \ddot{b} \ddot{c}+\overline{b}\overline{c}\ddot{\gamma}$$

Thus, defining $x_2:=\frac12x$ for convenience, we can expand $\cos\alpha$ and $\cos\gamma$ using two versions of the half-angle identities $\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta_2=2\cos^2\theta_2-1$:
$$\begin{align}
\ddot{a} \ddot{d} + \overline{a} \overline{d} \;(1-2\overline{\alpha_2}^2) &= \ddot{b} \ddot{c} + \overline{b} \overline{c}\;(2\ddot{\gamma_2}^2-1) \tag2 \\[4pt]
\left(\ddot{a} \ddot{d} + \overline{a} \overline{d}\right) - \left(\ddot{b} \ddot{c}-\overline{b} \overline{c}\right) &=  
2\overline{a}\overline{d}\overline{\alpha_2}^2+2\overline{b}\overline{ c}\ddot{\gamma_2}^2
\tag3\\[4pt]
\cos(a-d)- \cos(b+c) &=  
2\overline{a}\overline{d}\overline{\alpha_2}^2+2\overline{b}\overline{ c}\ddot{\gamma_2}^2
\tag4\\[4pt]
2 \sin(-a_2 +b_2 + c_2 + d_2) \sin(a_2 + b_2 + c_2 -d_2) &=  
2\overline{a}\overline{d}\overline{\alpha_2}^2+2\overline{b}\overline{ c}\ddot{\gamma_2}^2
\tag5
\end{align}$$
Thus, with $s:=\frac12(a+b+c+d)$,

> $$\sin a\sin d\sin^2\alpha_2+\sin b\sin c\cos^2\gamma_2
> \;=\; \sin(s-a) \sin(s-d) \tag{$\star$}$$

Likewise,

> $$\sin a\sin d \cos^2\alpha_2 + \sin b \sin c \sin^2\gamma_2  \;=\; \sin(s-b)\sin(s-c) \tag{$\star\star$}$$

FYI, in [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines), the counterpart relations simply replace "$\sin(\text{length})$" with "$\sinh(\text{length})$".

Investigation of consequent "classical metric relations" is left as an exercise to the reader.