# Showing $\sum_{cyc}\tan\frac\alpha2\tan\frac\beta2\geq4$ for a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

> Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Denote $s$ the semiperimeter and let $\angle{DAB}=\alpha$, $\angle{ABC}=\beta$, $\angle{BCD}=\gamma$ and $\angle{CDA}=\delta$. Then the following inequality holds
>
> $$\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\geq4.\tag{1}$$

**Proof**. Substituting from the half-angle formula for the tangent (see $(2)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas)) we have that
$$\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-d)}{(s-b)(s-c)}}\cdot{\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{(s-c)(s-d)}}}=\frac{s-a}{s-c}.$$
Similarly,
$$\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{s-b}{s-d}\qquad\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}=\frac{s-c}{s-a}\qquad\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{s-d}{s-b}$$
Thus, the left-hand side of $(1)$ can be rewritten as follows
$$\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{s-a}{s-c}+\frac{s-b}{s-d}+\frac{s-c}{s-a}+\frac{s-d}{s-b}.$$
But,
$$\frac{s-a}{s-c}+\frac{s-b}{s-d}+\frac{s-c}{s-a}+\frac{s-d}{s-b}=\frac{a-c}{s-a}+\frac{b-d}{s-b}+\frac{c-a}{s-c}+\frac{d-b}{s-d}+4.$$
Since $\frac{a-c}{s-a}+\frac{c-a}{s-c}=\frac{4(a-c)^2}{(-a+b+c+d)(a+b-c+d)}$, and similarly for $\frac{b-d}{s-b}+\frac{d-b}{s-d}$, then $\frac{a-c}{s-a}+\frac{b-d}{s-b}+\frac{c-a}{s-c}+\frac{d-b}{s-d}$ is positive. Hence,

> $$\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\delta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\geq4.$$

Notice equality holds when $ABCD$ is rectangular.

A huge list of inequalities can be seen at [Cut-the-knot.org](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/InequalitiesInTriangle.shtml).

**Questions**: **a)** Is there a simpler way to prove $(1)$? **b)** Is $(1)$ known?

Comment: Use the [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) and the fact that $\alpha/2$ and $\gamma/2$ are complements (hence have reciprocal tangents), as are $\beta/2$ and $\delta/2$.

Comment: @Blue: Isn't the proof of the AM-GM inequality more complicated than my proof of $(1)$? I don't know, but I feel like cutting bread with a saw using AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Well, the two-term AM-GM is dead-simple. So, if we write $x$, $y$, $1/x$, $1/y$ for the tangents of the successive half-angles, the target sum is $$xy+\frac{y}{x}+\frac1{xy}+\frac{x}{y}=\left(x+\frac1x\right)\left(y+\frac1y\right)\geq 2\cdot 2=4$$ Ultimately, what "matters" is the reciprocal nature of the opposite half-angle tangents, which we get immediately from the cyclic nature of the quadrilateral. Your (neat!) formulas for those tangents *confirm* that reciprocal nature, but are themselves a bit like bread-saws with regard to the overall argument. :) ... Cheers!

Comment: @Blue: How $(x+\frac{1}{x})\geq2$? I do not see the standart version of the $AM-GM$ inequality here. Sorry, I couldn't sleep last night.

Comment: I mean, what version of the $AM-GM$ inequality are you using here?

Comment: For example, in Z Ahmed's answer, I can perfectly see what version of $AM-GM$ he is using. But my objection is that to prove the version he uses we need more sophisticated means than the ones I use.

Comment: The relation $x+\frac1x\geq2$ is an application of the AM-GM instance $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$. See the picture-proof at the top of the Wikipedia ["Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), or [the variant at my Trigonography site](https://trigonography.com/2015/10/01/a-reciprocal-sum-inequality/).

Comment: That is definitely much simpler. Perhaps asking about the following inequality is less obvious:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tan\frac\alpha2\tan\frac\beta2>\frac{a-c}{s-a}-\frac{a-c}{s-c}+\frac{b-d}{s-b}-\frac{ b-d}{s-d}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AM_GM

$F=\frac{s-a}{s-c}+\frac{s-b}{s-d}+\frac{s-c}{s-a}+\frac{s-d}{s-b}\ge 4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{s-a}{s-c}\frac{s-b}{s-d}\frac{s-c}{s-a}\frac{s-d}{s-b}}=4.$